# Equal Height Columns with border-right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a column layout where all of the columns are of equal heights so the borders extend down to the same length.  I've tried a couple solutions including the One True Layout Solution proposed at http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/, but that caused the borders to disappear entirely.  I also tried using display: table for the wrapper, but that's not supported by IE7.

Here is my code so you can see what I'm referring to:

http://jsfiddle.net/kh9nS/1/

Thanks.

Comment: maybe you should try this one <http://www.code-sucks.com/css layouts/faux-css-layouts/> no (41 or 42) it looks much similar. hope it works for you.. good luck..

Comment: Will the column heights adjust constantly or will they be static?

Comment: I just briefly took a look at the css & I think that the height of all the div's are dynamic they is no constant height declared.

Comment: If this Style make sense to you then we can try to merge your CSS with this which suits your need.

Comment: The heights of the content will change, so we can't use any type of fixed height solution.

I looked the solutions @Scorpio provided, but when I add a border to any of those column divs it doesn't extend all the way down.

Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

I tryied CSS Table and Actual table in your css-tricks link, and it works.

Comment: That method does work, but unfortunately it isn't supported in IE7.  If we can find a way to make it work in IE7, then that would be a great solution.

Comment: This is Jquery solution, try it. http://demo.smartnetzone.com/same-height-columns-using-jquery/

Comment: the jQuery example only works if you have one set of columns on the page at a time.  The users will have the ability to add multiple sets of columns.  Plus, I'd love to avoid using Javascript for something like this.  Thanks though.  That script is short and sweet.

Comment: We ended up going with display: table and left out IE7.  It's really progressive enhancement anyways, since the columns still load, they just don't have equal height.  Plus, our clients were only getting about 2% of their traffic from IE7.